# restful authentication current_user

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Is it available in the controller, because it's not working for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does your `ApplicationController` class contain the lines shown below?

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  include AuthenticatedSystem
  helper :all
  ...
end
```